# Inheriting Constructors in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

So I have a base class called Weapon:

```
/*Weapon.h*/
#ifndef WEAPON_H
#define WEAPON_H
/*Weapon Class*/
class Weapon
{
    int damage = 0,attackSpeed = 0;
public:
     Weapon(int inDamage, int inAttackSpeed) : damage(inDamage), attackSpeed(inAttackSpeed) {};
```

And a class called Sword that inherits Weapons attributes, I want to inherit the constructor too:

```
/*Sword.cpp*/
#include "Weapon.h"
#ifndef SWORD_H
#define SWORD_H
class Sword : public Weapon
{
public:
    using Weapon::Weapon;//inherit weapons constructor
```

However when I called it in my main function it gets an error saying the arguments invalid and its not a constructor:

```
/*Main.cpp*/
#include <iostream>
#include "Sword.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    Weapon weapon(5,5);
    Sword sword(10,10); <-- Error here, invalid parameters
```

I want to inherit Weapons constructor, but I must be missing something.

Comment: Does the compiler fully support C++11?

Comment: The code looks OK. It look like your compiler doesn't support inheriting constructors. This is one or the latest C++11 features to be supported by the more popular compilers.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2013 Professional, I assume it would....

Comment: Looks like compiler isn't supporting this.

Comment: @user3044002: Have you used `-std=c++11` parameter?

Comment: @user3044002, Assuming MSVC is standard-conforming isn't a great idea. It's getting better, though.

Comment: [This table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh567368.aspx#corelanguagetable) implies that your compiler doesn't support inheriting constructors yet.

Comment: @gexicide No I have not, where would I put that/ what is the correct syntax for that code?

Comment: @gexicide, C++11 is enabled by default on MSVC.

Comment: [This table](https://h70tha.dm2302.livefilestore.com/y2pO_T96yqnsay4tnPVnyTEENlK3YRiIV0uKLAaDg8O1qSB5bjhnYKyUlDm2ZOU8a6rXgqV9dZGU2sHOpN3ziLXEPLJCIVH0dWYLbhJ_jGrCAs/cppconform.png?psid=1) says it's supported as of the November 2013 CTP.

Answer (score 2):

@Mike Seymour seems to be right, [Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 does not support inheriting constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh567368.aspx#corelanguagetable).